# Display random image using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone i'm trying to display some random images while **not loading (refresh) page**

So how can i display random images on a page without refreshing the page ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get", url: "Home/Oku", data: {}, dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   var newFirmDiv= $(' <img src="../../banner_image/' + data[i] + '" width="154px" height="108px"/>');
                   $(".firmShowCase").append(newFirmDiv);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my action method that provides return values an array

```
 public ActionResult Oku()
    {
        var query = from table in db.news select table.news_image_name;
        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is result as you can see below

[image]

Comment: Well it looks like you're already making an attempt at it, so how's that going?

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this is finally what you were looking for

Comment: Whay don't you get the images as html and display them easily? Select images `order by rand()` and send it as html output.

Answer (score 0):

**2nd Try:**

function for min and max

(http://www.naden.de/blog/zufallszahlen-in-javascript-mit-mathrandom)

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
 if(min > max) {
  return -1;
 }

 if(min == max) {
 return min;
 }

 var r;

 do {
 r = Math.random();
 }
 while(r == 1.0);
 return min + parseInt(r * (max-min+1));
}
```

And Your Code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        randomIndex = getRandom(0, data.length-1);
        var newFirmDiv= $(' <img src="../../banner_image/' + data[randomIndex] + '"width="154px" height="108px"/>');
        $(".firmShowCase").append(newFirmDiv);
    }
```

**If you want to keep the random order...**

...you have to save it like in a new array, afterwards you could save it via ajax in a database or a temp file. And the top of your current file you would have to check if there is an existing temp file; if it shall be bound to a user, you could generate a random key (like with time) save it in a session variable and name the tmp file or the data in the database with the same random key... so far my ideas, if it's that what you are looking for. Of cause it would be easier to do this on the server side right from the start.

**First Answer:**

(The question was not really clear - if something does not work and so on...)

First of all data is not returned as an array, but an object. But i think you do not understand the parameters of the ajax function very well.

In the url parameter should be the script (for example getImages.php) which shall be executed. So there you should collect the images, parse them to jason and print them, in that way it will be returned as data.

In the parameter data you can pass some params to the skript, which you can get by decoding them in php.

I just chose PHP for example.

If I am wrong and "Home/Oku" leads to some script you might show us what it does?

Comment: No no data is returned as an array because i'm using asp.net MVC3 and my action method returns values in array so i have no problem with the array

Comment: No, you are wrong, it does not matter what you are using, because your chosen data type is json, so you will get back a json object, if you are returning some data... so is a script executed on server side or not? Then show us. The theoretics about ajax is, to send a request to a script on the server side. Edit: The data type is for the sent not the returned data, so yes you can print an array, see my next comment

Comment: Sorry, no you are right, you could get data back in an array, the type is for the sent data, not the returned one, but so please just show us the script which shall handle taht call, though I still guess taht your url param is off

Comment: And please tell us what happens or not happens ;-) Did you alert/log the returned date? Is it fine? Are the elements appended at all?

Comment: So your only question after all... is how to print it randomly? That was not clear, somehow... I will edit my Answer

Comment: yes my only question is only print randomly:)) but images change automatically

Comment: So does my new answer help you?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ganymedes/QR79n/ here is my effect you will understand what i mean :)) but i display randomly. Okay your code provides to display images randomly but  it shows images when you refresh the page

Comment: I am sorry, but I do still not understand what you mean... the js is executed after the pageload and the ajax should do its job without you having to relaod the page... or do you want them to be still that way after the reload? Or is your problem, that it takes a little moment, before the ajax callback action is executed?

Comment: I added dome ideas babove if you want to keep the random order after the refresh.